# Visual Studio not letting login after clearing the cache

Tags: authentication, visual-studio-2019

After facing the problem mention at below URL and trying the solution given, visual studio is not getting login.
[An attempt to communicate with Azure DevOps failed because a token could not be retrieved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60167891/an-attempt-to-communicate-with-azure-devops-failed-because-a-token-could-not-be)

Now Facing the error - "we could not refresh the credentials for the account. Request to the endpoint is timed out"[image]

Answer (score 0):

Login with Product key solved the issue.
Earlier I was trying using my account, but that was giving me the error.